# PostgreSQL запрос с использованием json_agg и вложенных SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет. Есть некая серия таблиц, условно говоря таблица портфелей, папок и документов.
Хочу сделать 1 запрос PostgreSQL 9 такого вида:

```
SELECT p.*, (
     SELECT json_agg(row(f.*, (
               SELECT json_agg(row(d.*)) 
               FROM doc d 
               WHERE d.folder = f.id
                ) as docs
      )) 
     FROM folder f 
     WHERE f.portfel_id = p.id
     ) as folders 
 FROM portfel p;
```

При попытке пихнуть json_agg в json_agg возникает ошибка 42601 (SYNTAX). Есть ли руководство как сделать это дело правильно?

Comment: Приведите исходные данные и требуемый результат

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался со всем сам. В общем, идея такова, что привести все внутренние SELECT к такому виду, чтобы ещё одним `SELECT json_agg(x.*) FROM (SELECT ... ) x` можно было бы схватить всё что нужно.
То бишь `SELECT json_agg(row(a.*, (SELECT ... ) as t1)) FROM ...` заменяется на

```
SELECT json_agg(x.*) FROM (SELECT a.*, (SELECT b.* FROM table2 b) FROM table a)) x;
```

и далее эта штука применяется рекурсивно. То есть если выше стоял дочерний запрос, то можно сделать ещё

```
SELECT json_agg(y.*) FROM (SELECT c.*, (SELECT json_agg(x.*) FROM (SELECT a.*, (SELECT b.* FROM table2 b) FROM table a)) x) as t2 FROM table 3 c) y
```

и т.д.